# No nodes available to schedule pods

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks

I tried to create an EKS Kubernetes cluster, for example using this: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/tree/master/examples/eks-getting-started

What I get is all pods are pending:

> No nodes available to schedule pods

in `kubectl po describe` and I get an empty list when I type `kubectl get nodes`.

Changing AMI images or AWS region doesn't help.

What's wrong?

Comment: Would highly recommend using this module instead: https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks

Comment: Consider sharing some more information/logs, for example what's the output of `kubectl cluster-info` or `kubectl cluster-info dump`?

Comment: Fortunately the module github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks helped. Now the cluster works. Thank you.

Comment: can you share output from kubectl describe node <node-name>

Answer (score 2):

I was still having issue with the code where the worker nodes register only if eks was set to public subnets only.

`module "eks" {
   subnets                              = ["${module.vpc.public_subnets}"]
}`

I did not want my workers to be in public subnets. I changed

```
module "eks" {
   subnets                              = ["${module.vpc.private_subnets}"]
}

module "vpc" {
   single_nat_gateway = false
}
```

kubectl get nodes

```
NAME                                       STATUS    ROLES     AGE       VERSION
ip-10-0-1-247.us-east-2.compute.internal   Ready     <none>    17m       v1.11.5
ip-10-0-1-75.us-east-2.compute.internal    Ready     <none>    17m       v1.11.5
ip-10-0-2-225.us-east-2.compute.internal   Ready     <none>    17m       v1.11.5
ip-10-0-3-210.us-east-2.compute.internal   Ready     <none>    17m       v1.11.5
```

Answer (score 0):

As Matt mentioned https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks helped. More specifically I just used the example from https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/tree/master/examples/eks_test_fixture

All the other examples or running EKS cluster I found on the Internet don't work.

Comment: Link is dead, could you describe what solved your issue?

Comment: Don't remember exactly. But anyway, I stopped using eks and used kops. Eks costs, the cost of kops is only the cost of your instances, and it doesn't make any problems.